# Do repeated Booyahs power up the Booyah Bomb?

Tags: splatoon-3

The Booyah Bomb's description says that it can be powered up by sending and receiving Booyahs from your team. Does the power of a teammate's Booyah Bomb increase more if I use the Booyah button more than once?

Comment: Since you only get the bonus on your special once and after Booyah-ing once the message dissapears, I would say its a safe bet that your allies can only boost it once.

Answer (score 4):

[According to the wiki](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Booyah_Bomb#Data), Booyah bomb can register up to five booyah's (Ambiguos as to 5 global booyah's or 5 per ally. It seems to be 5 global according to this [video](https://youtu.be/rn6Q_pP_cd8?t=3198) as an example. You can see only five orbs coming out of the allies in total), granting different bomb increases values and special charge values to each ally.

Values may be incorrect since it refers to splatoon 2 rather than 3, but you can see some consistency between the video and the wiki.

Comment: I wonder if a player could fully power up their own Booyah Bomb by Booyah-ing 5 times.

Comment: @pinckerman Just tested in the lobby, you can power up your own Booyah Bomb. Working on an answer now.

Comment: Yes, you can power up your own booyah, the limit for the booyah is for the allies, not yourself. I only mentioned ally booyah's since your question is specific to them.

Comment: @BunnyMerz That's a good point. I hadn't considered a distinction between self-Booyahs and teammate Booyahs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, repeated Booyahs will make a Booyah Bomb charge significantly faster.

I Booyahed a teammate multiple times in a multiplayer match and saw multiple beams of energy sent their way.

[image: sending booyah energy]

I also tested in the lobby by sending myself Booyahs. The Booyah Bomb took around 6 seconds to charge with a single Booyah as opposed to 2 and a half seconds when I Booyahed ten times by spamming the button.

Comment: Good to know you don't need friends to use it, but it kinda loses its purpose now :')

Comment: @pinckerman I've seen it charge faster with other players booyahing, since 4 mashers are faster than 1.